# Why do I get an "unexpected operator" error for my condition in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I got the code for monitoring apache. The name of the file is `test.sh`. I changed the code a bit.

What I was looking for is, when I do:

```
./test.sh -H localhost -wr 2 -cr 5 -arg cpu_load
```

It should test apache for its `cpu_load`, i.e., I tried to control monitoring apache with my `-arg` parameter, but that doesn't seem to be working.

When I run this:

```
./test.sh -H localhost -wr 2 -cr 5 -arg cpu_load
```

I get the error :

```
./test.sh: 282: [: -ge: unexpected operator
./test.sh: 286: [: -ge: unexpected operator
```

Here is some part of the code:

```
#!/bin/sh


while test -n "$1"; do
    case "$1" in
        --help|-h)
            print_help
            exit $ST_UK
            ;;
        --version|-v)
            print_version $PROGNAME $VERSION
            exit $ST_UK
            ;;
        --hostname|-H)
            hostname=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --port|-P)
            port=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --timeout|-t)
            timeout=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --remote-server|-R)
            remote_srv=1
            ;;
        --binary_path|-b)
            path_binary=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --pid_path|-p)
            path_pid=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --pid_name|-n)
            name_pid=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --status-page|-s)
            status_page=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --secure|-S)
            secure=1
            ;;
        --warning-req|-wr)
            warn_req=$2
            shift
            ;;
        --critical-req|-cr)
            crit_req=$2
            shift
            ;;
    --userargument|-arg)
       user_arg=$3
       shift
           ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown argument: $1"
            print_help
            exit $ST_UK
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

#other codes

    if [ ${wclvls_req} = 1 ]
    then
        if [ ${user_arg} -ge ${warn_req} -a ${user_arg} -lt ${crit_req} ]
        then
            echo "WARNING - ${output} | ${perfdata}"
            exit $ST_WR
        elif [ ${user_arg} -ge ${crit_req} ]
        then
            echo "CRITICAL - ${output} | ${perfdata}"
        exit $ST_CR
        else
            echo "OK - ${output} | ${perfdata}"
            exit $ST_OK
        fi
    else
        echo "OK - ${output} | ${perfdata}"
        exit $ST_OK
    fi

fi
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of your variables ( `user_arg`, `warn_req` etc ) in the `if` condition might be empty.

Better way to write that is with quoting the variables as (which may fail in your case if you want to compare as integers):

```
if [ "${user_arg}" -ge "${warn_req}" -a "${user_arg}" -lt "${crit_req}" ]
```

Or another way is to specify the default values so that if variable is null or undefined if won't fail as below.

```
if [ ${user_arg:-0} -ge ${warn_req:-0} -a ${user_arg:-0} -lt ${crit_req:-0} ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need POSIX compatibility, you can use bash's arithmetic evaluation command instead:

```
if (( user_arg >= 0 && user_arg < crit_req )); then
```

Unset variables will be implicitly treated as 0-valued, so using default value expansion is unnecessary.